# Best ability based authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

I have a Rails 3 app, where i use CanCan for authorization, but i am looking for something that suits my needs better. My authorizations is not very role based, but really more situational.

The application is for managing daily dinner clubs at a college/dorm, where the people takes turn making dinner for the rest. A chef have therefore more permissions for the dinner club he is responsible for (like changing the menu), and a participant have more permissions (like adding guests) then one who is not participating in that single dinner club.

What i need is therefore some authorization system that depends on the relationship between the user and the dinner club or kitchen (a kitchen have many dinner clubs), not the users role.

If it helps, are my current cancan abilities here (as you see they are pretty complex)

```
# In ability.rb

def initialize(user)
  # edit (like changing time or menu) for a dinner club
  can :edit, DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    dinner_club.is_chef?(user) &&
    !dinner_club.canceled?
  end

  # open or close a dinner club
  can [:open, :close], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    !dinner_club.passed? &&
    dinner_club.is_chef?(user)
  end

  # cancel or resume a dinner club
  can [:cancel, :resume], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    !dinner_club.passed? &&
    dinner_club.is_chef?(user)
  end

  # register or unregister for at specific dinner club
  can [:register, :unregister], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    dinner_club.open? &&
    (dinner_club.kitchen_id == user.kitchen_id || dinner_club.kitchen.open_registrations?) &&
    !dinner_club.is_chef?(user)
  end

  # add guests to a dinner club
  can [:add_guests], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    dinner_club.open? &&
    (dinner_club.kitchen_id == user.kitchen_id || dinner_club.kitchen.open_registrations?) &&
    dinner_club.registered?(user)
  end

  # take the dinner club from another use if the dinner club is canceled
  can [:take], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    dinner_club.canceled? &&
    (dinner_club.kitchen_id == user.kitchen_id || dinner_club.kitchen.open_registrations?) &&
    !dinner_club.passed? &&
    !dinner_club.is_chef?(user)
  end

  # create a new dinner club
  can [:create], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    (dinner_club.kitchen_id == user.kitchen_id || dinner_club.kitchen.open_registrations?)
  end

  # comment on existing dinner clubs
  can [:comment], DinnerClub do |dinner_club|
    dinner_club.registered?(user)
  end

  # can see dinner clubs for this kitchen
  can :read, Kitchen do |kitchen|
    (kitchen.id == user.kitchen_id || kitchen.open_registrations?)
  end

  # can manage the kitchen, like changing name and configuration options
  can :manage, Kitchen, admin_id: user.id
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite most of these blocks in CanCan to make them a lot less complex.

```
can :edit, DinnerClub, cancelled: false, chef_id: user.id

# open or close a dinner club
can [:open, :close], DinnerClub, passed: false, chef_id: user.id

# take the dinner club from another use if the dinner club is canceled
can [:take], DinnerClub, cancelled: true, kitchen_id: user.kitched_id, passed: false  
can [:take], DinnerClub, cancelled: true, kitchen: { open_registrations: true }, passed: false
cannnot [:take], DinnerClub, chef_id: user.id
```

This is assuming the `cancelled?` and `passed?` methods are derived from boolean attributes on the DinnerClub model and that the `is_chef?` method checks a chef_id. But it illustrates the idea.

CanCan is mostly used to define abilities based on resources, so I would go with that.

Comment: Thank you this helps! What about thing that is not really authorization oriented like implementing that you can only close a dinner club if it's open, and vice versa, should i also do this with cancan or do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: I have now rewritten a lot of my ability logic, and it looks much better. However i still feel that CanCan not is the best choice for my kind of authorization...

Comment: You problably want to use a state machine for that. Check out https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine. I believe there is a railscast about this as well by Ryan Bates, you could look at that too.